# Spring boot automated build with Docker cloud

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, continuous-deployment

I am trying to achieve Continuous Integration/Delivery with Docker Cloud.

On Docker Cloud i connected my bit bucket repository, so on every commit docker build will initiate on Docker Cloud, but automated build are failing, these are the logs

> ERROR: Build failed: ADD failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder406751627/target/springtest.jar: no
>   such file or directory ERROR: Build failed with exit code 2 ERROR:
>   Build in 'master' (094341b2) failed in 0:02:10

**This is my Docker File**

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD /target/springtest.jar springtest.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","springtest.jar"]
```

However if i try to build the same thing on my Local Docker Terminal i am not getting Issues, i am using this command `mvn package docker:build` and its creating Images Successfully

So why with the same Dockerfile automated build ? Any other step i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **springtest.jar** in your local?

From error seems to be Docker Cloud is not able to find springtest.jar file.

Comment: I am not trying in local environment.   I have created a repository in Docker Cloud and i have set up Automatic build. Once i commit anything on Bit Bucket automatically build will be initiated on Docker Cloud (So the same build is failing)

Comment: ok, but in that automatic build do you have springtest.jar? in same location?

Comment: How is jar supposed to be built on Docker cloud build? Is there a build descriptor file?